# Logon-type wxpython app

Tags: windows, authentication, wxpython, modal-dialog

I manage a number of Windows PCs which are used to control equipment. Each computer has a specific program installed which is what people launch to use that equipment. We want to require people to log in before they can access this program.

Currently, I have a wxpython app which just launches that executable when people log in with the correct credentials. However, you can just run the program directly and bypass logging on. I'd like to make a mock logon screen, ie, fullscreen and modal, which only goes away when you log in. Also it should not be able to be bypassed by alt-tab, windows key, etc. How might I accomplish this with wxpython?

Comment: How is the credentials handled? How do they log in?

Comment: I have a python server process running on a Linux server. It ties into their credentials on a Drupal site. When they input their username and password, it send their name and md5'ed password over a socket, which is checked with the site for validity, authorization on that computer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no full proof way to do this on Windows. You can show a wx.Frame modally using its MakeModal() method. And you can catch EVT_CLOSE and basically veto it it they try to close the frame. However, if they have access to the Task Manager or even Run, they can probably get around the screen. Most users won't be that smart though. You can delete the shortcuts to the apps you want to launch with wx and that will force most normal users to use your login screen. It's only the smart ones who like to troll through the file system who will go around it.

Comment: Alright. Yeah at the moment I have the shortcuts hidden, but the people using these computers are all scientific researchers, so they are definitely on the "smart" side ;). I can disable task manager...is there a way of catching (and vetoing) key sequences such as the windows key or alt-tab? I know I won't be able to veto ctrl+alt+delete, but if I disable task manager it won't be a problem I think.

Comment: Since your frame will be in focus, you might be able to catch the Windows key and just ignore it. You'd have to experiment with EVT_CHAR and EVT_KEY_DOWN to see if you can catch alt-tab. I really don't know if it can be caught or not.